# How to send formData in angular with a file to spring boot backend

Tags: angular, multipartform-data

I am using angular6 to send formData with user details along with a image file. But I couldn't get the data in spring boot backend by using @ModelAttribute for the RequestModel.

Comment: This is not the way to ask question because no one can understand. please share same code what you have done till now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Please change the spring boot backend code with two parameters. Those two parameters should be the values of fromData key used in angular. First key should should be the file which contains image and second key should the other parameters in the form which is stringified using JSON.stringify()

    @PostMapping("/advocate_ad")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public ResponseEntity<?> saveAdvocateAd(@RequestParam(value="image") MultipartFile image,@RequestParam(value="advocateAd") String advocateAdForm ) {

         try {
             ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
             AdvocateAdForm advocateAd = mapper.readValue(advocateAdForm,AdvocateAdForm.class);
            AdvocateAd advocateAd1 = new AdvocateAd(advocateAd.getTargetCities(),advocateAd.getStatus().charAt(0),advocateAd.getSummary(),
                    advocateAd.getDetails(),advocateAd.getUrl(),advocateAd.getCreationDate(),advocateAd.getValidityStartDate(),
                    advocateAd.getValidityEndDate(),advocateAd.getAdvocateId(),image.getBytes());
            advocateAdService.save(advocateAd1);


             return  ResponseEntity.ok().build();

        }catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
             return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);

        }

Angular 6 code `export class AdminModule1 {
  advocateId: number;
  summary: string;
  targetCities: string;
  details: string;
  url: string;
  status: string;
  creationDate: string;
  validityStartDate: string;
  validityEndDate: string;
  image: File;
}`
`  
Service File
    let formData=new FormData();
    formData.append('advocateAd',JSON.stringify(value));
    formData.append('image',param.image);
    //console.log(formData);
    return this.http.post<string>(admin,formData);
  }`
```